# Javascript - value of varname

Tags: javascript, variables

Declaration of var in javascript shoud looks like this

```
var varname1 [= value1 [, varname2 [, varname3 ... [, varnameN]]]];
```

valueN - Initial value of the variable. It can be any legal expression.

Can you provide me an exemple of that legal expression?

Answer (score 1):

> Can you provide me an exemple of that legal expression?

As mention in the [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Expressions_and_Operators#Expressions)

> Expressions
>
> An expression is any valid unit of code that resolves to a value.
>
> Conceptually, there are two types of expressions: those that assign a
>   value to a variable and those that simply have a value.

```
var a = 10;

var a = 20+24;
```

this is also a expression

```
var age = 3;
var str = ["I'm only", age, "years old"].join(" ");
```

Comment: @Karolina Ticha: could you tell us whether our answer has been work for you or still have some issue ?

Answer (score 1):

generally `[]` means optional. What your statement here means is that you can define any number of variables using a single `var`, separated by commas and you can assign(initialize) those variables at the same time.

Take this

```
var varname1 [= value1];
```

means `varname1` can be initialized while defining otherwise

```
var varname1;
```

or

```
var varname1 = value1;
```

like wise

```
var varname1 [= value1 [, varname2 [= value2]]];
```

can be

```
var varname1 = value1, varname2 = value2;
var varname1 = value1, varname2;
var varname1, varname2 = value2;
var varname1 = value1;
var varname1;
etc
```

for ex:

```
var a = 1, b = 2, c, d, e = 5;
```